# I would like to receive the contact details of the Authors for Patent WO2014067081A

Tags: search

I am interested in contacting the authors. Please help if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the papers filed by the applicants with the PatentScope link. This is one page from the "Request".

[image]